# Symfony 3.1 and OneUpUploaderBundle + FineUploader = UploadListener is not called

Tags: php, symfony, fine-uploader, oneupuploaderbundle

### INTRODUCTION

I am developing on `Windows 10 Pro` with `XAMPP` [1] which includes `PHP v7.0.8`.

- [1] [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

I am using Symfony v3.1.2, [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) in order to upload files to server.

While setting things up I followed documentation of `OneUpUploaderBundle` [2] and `FineUploader` [3], [4].

- [2] [OneupUploaderBundle documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [3] [OneupUploaderBundle FineUploader example](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_fineuploader.md)
- [4] [FineUploader upload documentation](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html)

### PROBLEM

File upload works fine and files are uploaded to `oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery')`.

However listener is not called and is displayed in Symfony Profiler Events section `Not Called Listeners`

### CODE

relevant part of `services.yml`

```
app.upload_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onUpload }
```

my upload listener

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;

class UploadListener
{
    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $original_filename = $request->files->get('fineuploader')->getClientOriginalName();
        echo $original_filename;
    }
}
```

upload.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('js/fineuploader/fine-uploader-new.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row clearfix">
        Go to: <a href="{{ path('product_list') }}">Product list</a>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="uploader"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/fineuploader/fine-uploader.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                    <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                    <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
                </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                <li>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                    <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
                element: document.getElementById('uploader'),
                request:
                {
                    endpoint: "{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}"
                },
                validation:
                {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'gif']
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

### UPDATE

1. Added a note about development environment.

### CONCLUSION

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Found similar question (but for Symfony2) without answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296486/oneupuploaderbundle-upload-picture-but-doesnt-call-eventlistener/32296931#comment63807369_32296931

Comment: I created similar question, but with different uplaod library
[OneUpUplaoderBundle and Blueimp jQuery upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295832/symfony-3-1-and-oneupuploadbundle-blueimp-uploadlistener-is-not-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in question was caused by misconfiguration of `event listeners` in `services.yml`. Here is working configuration.

my services.yml

```
services:
    app.upload_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.gallery, method: onPostUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.gallery, method: onUpload }

    app.upload_unique_namer:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadUniqueNamer
        arguments: ["@session"]
```