# Symfony 3.1 and OneUpUploaderBundle + Blueimp = UploadListener is not called

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, blueimp, oneupuploaderbundle

### INTRODUCTION

Almost two weeks ago I created similar question about upload using `OneupUploaderBundle`, but with [FineUploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055561/symfony-3-1-and-oneupuploadbundle-fineuploader-uploadlistener-is-not-called) library. Sadly there are no answers yet.
In the meantime I tried setting up different upload library.

I am developing on `Windows 10 Pro` with `XAMPP` [1] which includes `PHP v7.0.8`.

- [1] [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

I am using Symfony v3.1.5, [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and [Blueimp jQuery upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in order to upload files to server.

While setting things up I followed documentation of `OneUpUploaderBundle` [2] and `jQuery file upload` [3], [4].

- [2] [OneupUploaderBundle documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [3] [OneupUploaderBundle Blueimp example](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_blueimp.md)
- [4] [Blueimp jQuery file upload documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)

### PROBLEM

I want to upload files to some directory and then check their [mime type](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getMimeType) and validate is file mime type allowed for uploading and after that - move them to custom directory (that can change from file to file), finally i want to persist file path and file name to database.

File upload works fine and files are uploaded to `oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery')`. Even custom file `Namer` works and allows upload to custom directory.

However, **listeners are not called** (upload listeners and validation) and are displayed in Symfony Profiler Events section `Not Called Listeners`!

That is unfortunate, as I want to save info about file to database using `Post_Persist` event. [OneupUploaderBundle events](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/bde473d4cadabc752e072ae8487bf8d9bd429d9c/Resources/doc/events.md).

### CODE

my services.yml

```
services:
    app.upload_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onPostUpload }

    app.upload_unique_namer:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadUniqueNamer
        arguments: ["@session"]
```

my custom Namer

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Uploader\Naming;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\File\FileInterface;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming\NamerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class UploadUniqueNamer implements NamerInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user directory name for the file being uploaded.
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file
     * @return string The directory name.
     */
    public function name(FileInterface $file)
    {
        $upload_files_path = $this->session->get('upload_files_path');
        $unique_name = uniqid();

        return sprintf('%s/%s_%s',
            $upload_files_path,
            $unique_name,
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );
    }
}
```

my config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_unique_namer
            use_orphanage: false
            allowed_mimetypes: [image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif]
            max_size: 200M
```

my upload listener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

class UploadListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    //protected $originalName;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $this->originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $object = new Product();
        $object->setName($file->getClientOriginalName());
        //$object->setName($file->getPathName());

        $this->entityManager->persist($object);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

upload.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/blueimp/jquery.fileupload.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="box-list" class="clearfix">
        Go to: <a href="{{ path('product_list') }}">Product list</a>
    </div>
    <div id="box-upload">
        <div id="box-file-upload">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>&nbsp;Choose files...</span>
                    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" />
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="box-progress">
            <div id="box-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-info">
            <p>Upload status...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.1.0.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.ui.widget.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.iframe-transport.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blueimp/jquery.fileupload.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            'use strict';
            $('#file-upload').on('click', function ()
            {
                $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '1%');
            });

            $('#file-upload').on("fileuploadprocessfail", function(e, data)
            {
                var file = data.files[data.index];
                alert(file.error);
                console.log(file.error);
            });

            $('#file-upload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                add: function (e, data)
                {
                    var fileName = data.files[0].name;
                    var fileType = data.files[0].name.split('.').pop();
                    var allowedTypes = 'jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF';
                    if (allowedTypes.indexOf(fileType) < 0)
                    {
                        $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '0');
                        $('<p/>').text(fileName).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        $('<p class="wrong-file-type"/>').text('Invalid file type').appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('<p/>').text(fileName).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                        if ($('.button-upload').length == 0)
                        {
                            // disabling file input
                            $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', true);

                            data.context = $('<button class="button-upload btn btn-primary start"/>').text('Upload')
                                    .appendTo($('#box-info'))
                                    .click(function ()
                                    {
                                        data.context = $('<p class="upload-success"/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                                        ($('.button-cancel')).remove();
                                        data.submit();
                                    });
                            $('<button class="button-cancel btn btn-warning cancel" />').text('Cancel')
                                    .appendTo($('#box-info'))
                                    .click(function ()
                                    {
                                        $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', '0');
                                        //console.log('testing');
                                        var message = 'Upload canceled';
                                        ($('.button-upload')).remove();
                                        ($('.button-cancel')).remove();
                                        $('<p class="wrong-file-type"/>').text(message).appendTo($('#box-info'));
                                        // enabling file input
                                        $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', false);
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                progressall: function (e, data)
                {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $('#box-progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
                },
                done: function (e, data)
                {
                    data.context.text('Upload finished.');
                    // enabling file input
                    $('input#file-upload').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

### UPDATES

1. Added a note about development environment.
2. Tried same code with Symfony v2.8.8, sadly UploadListener is not called.
3. Edited `services.yml`, removed (I think) now unnecessary (duplicated - provided in OneupUploaderBundle) validation that I added while trying to make it work...

### CONCLUSION

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just listen to the right event. 
Event exchange contains the name of your mapping, in order that you can implement a specific logic to this one that will not affect the others.

Event to this format.

```
oneup_uploader.post_upload.{mapping}
```

In your case it will give

```
oneup_uploader.post_upload.gallery
```

For more informations, please read
https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/events.md

Comment: Yes, looks that the problem was misconfiguration of services on my part.
Indeed, `oneup_uploader.post_persist.gallery` instead of `...default_uploader` works. Curiously `...default_uploader` was only auto complete item that PHPStorm offered. In the meantime events are still shown in Event Dispather `Not Called Listeners` section, though I can confirm that events now fire and I can save info about files to database. Thanks again.