# Symfony 3.1 and OneUpUploaderBundle + Plupload = UploadListener is not called

Tags: php, symfony, plupload, oneupuploaderbundle

### CLARIFICATION

This question differ from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055561/symfony-3-1-and-oneupuploaderbundle-fineuploader-uploadlistener-is-not-calle) by that I am using different upload library (`Plupload` in this question versus `FineUploader` in similar question).

At the time of writing this question I did not know where the problem lied - so I expected usage of different library might show a way to the solution of the problem.

### INTRODUCTION

Three weeks ago I created similar question about upload using `OneupUploaderBundle`, but with [FineUploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055561/symfony-3-1-and-oneupuploadbundle-fineuploader-uploadlistener-is-not-called) library. Sadly there are no answers yet.
In the meantime I tried setting up different upload library (Blueimp).

One week ago I created similar question about upload using `OneupUploaderBundle`, but with [Blueimp jQuery uplaod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055561/symfony-3-1-and-oneupuploadbundle-fineuploader-uploadlistener-is-not-called) library. Sadly there are no answers yet. In the meantime I tried setting up different upload library (Plupload).

I am developing on `Windows 10 Pro` with `XAMPP` [1] which includes `PHP v7.0.8`.

- [1] [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

I am using Symfony v3.1.2, [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and [Plupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) library in order to upload files to server.

While setting things up I followed documentation of `OneUpUploaderBundle` [2] and `Plupload` upload library [3], [4].

- [2] [OneupUploaderBundle documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [3] [OneupUploaderBundle Plupload example](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/frontend_plupload.md)
- [4] [Plupload upload documentation](http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui)

### PROBLEM

I want to upload files to some directory and then check their [mime type](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html#method_getMimeType) and validate is file mime type allowed for uploading and after that - move them to custom directory (that can change from file to file), finally i want to persist file path and file name to database.

File upload works fine and files are uploaded to `oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery')`. Even custom file `Namer` works and allows upload to custom directory.

However, listeners are not called and are displayed in Symfony Profiler Events section `Not Called Listeners`!

That is unfortunate, as I want to move files to custom directory and save info about file to database unsing `Post_Persist` [event](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/bde473d4cadabc752e072ae8487bf8d9bd429d9c/Resources/doc/events.md). Additionally, validation is not called ether.

### CODE

my services.yml

```
services:
    app.upload_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onPostUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.default_uploader, method: onUpload }

    app.upload_unique_namer:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadUniqueNamer
        arguments: ["@session"]
```

my custom Namer

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Uploader\Naming;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\File\FileInterface;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming\NamerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class UploadUniqueNamer implements NamerInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user directory name for the file being uploaded.
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file
     * @return string The directory name.
     */
    public function name(FileInterface $file)
    {
        $upload_files_path = $this->session->get('upload_files_path');
        $unique_name = uniqid();

        return sprintf('%s/%s_%s',
            $upload_files_path,
            $unique_name,
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );
    }
}
```

my config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: plupload
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_unique_namer
            use_orphanage: false
            allowed_mimetypes: [image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif]
            max_size: 200M
```

my upload listener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

class UploadListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    //protected $originalName;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $this->originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        var_dump('In -- OnUpload');
        die();
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $object = new Product();
        $object->setName($file->getClientOriginalName());
        //$object->setName($file->getPathName());

        $this->entityManager->persist($object);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        var_dump('In -- OnPostUpload');
        die();
    }
}
```

upload.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.css') }}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery.ui.plupload/css/jquery.ui.plupload.css') }}" media="screen" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="box-upload">
        <div id="uploader">
            <p>Your browser doesn't have HTML5 support.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.2.4.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://bp.yahooapis.com/2.4.21/browserplus-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/plupload.full.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plupload/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $("#uploader").plupload(
            {
                // General settings
                runtimes : 'html5',
                url: "{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}",
                multi_selection: false,

                // Maximum file size
                max_file_size: '10mb',

                chunk_size: '1mb',

                // Resize images on clientside if we can
                resize: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    quality: 90,
                    crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
                },

                // Specify what files to browse for
                filters: [
                    {title: "Image files", extensions : "jpg,jpeg,png,gif"},
                    {title: "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi"}
                ],

                // Rename files by clicking on their titles
                rename: true,

                // Sort files
                sortable: true,

                // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
                dragdrop: true,

                // Views to activate
                views: {
                    list: true,
                    thumbs: false, // Show thumbs
                    active: 'list'
                },

                // Flash settings
                flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',

                // Silverlight settings
                silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'

            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

### UPDATES

1. none yet

### CONCLUSION

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in question was caused by misconfiguration of `event listeners` in `services.yml`. Here is working configuration.

my services.yml

```
services:
    app.upload_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.gallery, method: onPostUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist.gallery, method: onUpload }

    app.upload_unique_namer:
        class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadUniqueNamer
        arguments: ["@session"]
```